# Route String Added On Redirect.Response But Not Assigned To [RouteData] string

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, webforms-routing

I have a button that uses a code behind method to do stuff.  After finishing I have a Redirect.Response that should forward the user and use the route data string to get all products matching it.

Instead it is forwarding the user to the destination URL properly ([domain]/ScreeningDateTime/a38eceeb-5753-4156-ae2d-6a74cf7fef1e-64722426), but displaying all results from that table, instead of just results matching the RouteData string.

I wanted to note a few things:
I can enter [domain]/ScreeningDateTime?id=1 and have it work properly.
In debug (VS2013.3Pro) if I pin the InternalId it displays the string "a38eceeb-5753-4156-ae2d-6a74cf7fef1e-64722426" properly on the initial page.  On the ScreeningDateTime page, it does not.

Code with some stuff removed for brevity (I have tested it as it is displayed with the same results):

From the initial page

```
Response.Redirect(
            GetRouteUrl("ScreeningsByDateTimeRoute", new { internalId = InternalId }));
```

From the Global.asax

```
    void RegisterCustomRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute(
        "ScreeningsByDateTimeRoute",
        "ScreeningDateTime/{internalId}",
        "~/ScreeningDateTime.aspx"
        );

        *More Routes*
```

From the ScreeningDateTime code behind (Destination Page):

```
    public IQueryable<Screening> GetProducts(
        [QueryString("id")] int? id,
        [RouteData] string internalId)
    {
        var _db = new ProductContext();
        IQueryable<Screening> query = _db.Screenings;

        if (id.HasValue && id>0)
        {
            query = query.Where(p => p.ScreeningID == id);
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(internalId))
        {
            query = query.Where(p =>String.Compare(p.InternalId,internalId) == 0);
        }
        return query;
    }
```

If have looked for a fix for longer than I'd like to admit.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've always accessed route variables in `.aspx.cs` as `Page.RouteData.Values[variableName]`. Try this code:

```
public IQueryable<Screening> GetProducts()
{
    var _db = new ProductContext();
    IQueryable<Screening> query = _db.Screenings;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]))
    {
        query = query.Where(p => p.ScreeningID == Request.QueryString["id"]);
    }
    else if (Page.RouteData.Values["internalId"] != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Page.RouteData.Values["internalId"] as string))
    {
        query = query.Where(p => p.InternalId == Page.RouteData.Values["internalId"].ToString());
    }
    return query;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I'm wondering if you are using something like FriendlyURLs or URL rewriting and that is causing a conflict between `/ScreeningDateTime.aspx` and `/ScreeningDateTime/`. Try rename the route URL to something else, like:

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
        "ScreeningsByDateTimeRoute",
        "ScreeningDateTimeIntId/{internalId}",
        "~/ScreeningDateTime.aspx"
        );
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Tried with no success.
The InternalId value is still showing null.  It seemes to be an issue with my routing, but I am not sure.  It is routed to the proper URL, but once there the page isn't assigning the "{InternalId}" part of the "ScreeningDateTime/{InternalId}" to the routedata.  Like once there it just gets reset to null.

Comment: If that function is in a different class/library, could you try moving that function into the page itself and see if it works?

Comment: @ZombieBunnies added an update about potential route/url conflict.